# Testing graph isomorphism with powers of the adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two square, symmetric, binary matrices with null diagonal representing the adjacency matrices of undirected graphs.  If the multisets of the column-sums of $A$ and $B$ differ, then they are definitely not isomorphic.  If the column-sum multisets are the same, then $A$ and $B$ might be isomorphic.  Now I am wondering how the effectiveness of this test is improved by running it on $A^s$ and $B^s$ with a large integer $s$.  Are there any two non-isomorphic graphs that "look" the same in this sense for all $s$ or even for an infinite number of values of $s$?

Comment: The condition should imply that the two graphs are isospectral (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory#Isospectral_graphs), so I would look at known examples of isospectral but non-isomorphic graphs for counterexamples.

Comment: @Qiaochu, the article gives the examples $K_{1,4}$ and  $C_4 \cup K_1$ but I don't think this is the same.  $K_{1,4}$ has column-sum multiset $\{1,1,1,1,4\}$ and $C_4 \cup K_1$ has column-sum multiset $\{0,2,2,2,2\}$ so the test would correctly decide them to be non-isomorphic with $s=1$.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say that the two conditions are equivalent, but I am still pretty sure any counterexample has to be isospectral.

Comment: Dan's example of $C_3 \cup C_3$ and $C_6$ is not isospectral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly more generally than Dan's example, if a graph is $r$-regular, the column-sum multiset of $A^s$ is
$(r^s,\ldots,r^s)$.  So any two nonisomorphic $r$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

If $A = C_3 \cup C_3$ and $B = C_6$, then it seems like the column-sum multiset is always $\{2^s,2^s,2^s,2^s,2^s,2^s\}$.  I'm still interested in references and broader explanations.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I guess only the spectral radii need to be the same; extra structure may make the other eigenvalues of the graph irrelevant...

Answer (score 1):

Testing graph isomorphism by multiset of column sums of adjacency with any power is the same as what first order Weisfeiler-Lehman (1-WL test known as vertex coloring) test does. So that approach is definitely not powerful than 1-WL test and you cannot distinguish not just isospectral graphs but also the graphs whose just maximum eigenvalues are the same.

1-WL test starts checking column-sum (actually not necessarily sum but any injective function) of Adjacency matrix. Let's think all vertices are the same, If $a_0=b_0={\bf1}$ is a vector of enough 1s, 1-WL test checks if multiset of  $Aa_0$ and  $Bb_0$ are equal or not. To do that generally, we can use the sort function, so we can check if $sort(Aa_0)=sort(Bb_0)$. If they are the same, then 1-WL relabel the result after concatenating of the current color of the vertex and the previous step ($a_1=[a_0,~Aa_0]$ and $b_1=[b_0,~Bb_0]$), relabel $a_1$ and $b_1$ and repeat the process. Relabbellin process can be seen as assigning a unique identifier for each unique row of the concatenated colors of both graphs ($[a_1;b_1]$).

In the second turn, it checks if $sort(Aa_1)=sort(Bb_1)$. If they are the same, again relabelling and again checking. If they are not equal in any step it concludes that the graphs are not isomorphic at all, or if the relabelling process cannot change the color of vertices ($a_{t+1}=a_{t}$) then the algorithm stops and supposed they are isomorphic (still they might not be isomorphic). So, what you describe is a simplified version of 1-WL test which performs $S$ number of iteration. Because if we enroll the update and change the relabelling process by just assign new color of vertex (neglect the old color of vertex by $a_1=Aa_0$), after $S$ iteration, it checks $sort(A^S{\bf1})=sort(B^S{\bf1})$ which is exactly what you asked!

This algorithm definitely not powerful and be able to just find very very easy cases. Check higher-order Weisfeiler-Lehman test procedures.