# Can we recover the adjacency matrix of a graph from its square?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

For the sake of this question, a *graph* here has a finite number of vertices, with undirected simple edges, no loop, and no weight or label on edges or vertices. Therefore, its adjacency matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]$ is a symmetric matrix with entries in $\{0,1\}$, and $0$ on the main diagonal.

**Assuming that $A^2$ is known, can we recover $A$?**

The question comes from my self-study of graph theory and I have no idea on how to solve this question. What I know:

1. Let's label the vertices of the graph as $v_1$, $v_2$, $\dots$, $v_n$ so that $a_{i,j}=1$ if there is an edge between $v_i$ and $v_j$, and $0$ otherwise. Then, if $a_{i,j}^{(k)}$ is the entry of $A^k$ at row $i$ and column $j$, $a_{i,j}^{(k)}$ is the number of walks of length $k$ between $v_i$ and $v_j$. Therefore, what is known in the problem are the numbers $a_{i,j}^{(2)}$ of common neighbors between $v_i$ and $v_j$.
2. If the $i$th row of $A^2$ is composed of $0$s, then $v_i$ is an isolated point of the graph. (If $v_i$ is not isolated, then there is a walk $v_i-v_j-v_i$ so $a_{i,i}^{(2)}\ge 1$). So we can simplify the problem by assuming that the graph has no isolated point.
3. $a_{i,i}^{(2)}=1$ is equivalent to $\deg(v_i)=1$ (end vertex).
4. There are results about square roots of positive semi-definite matrices, but $A^2$ is not positive semi-definite, and the square root would not have its entries in $\{0,1\}$.
5. For $n=3$, by looking at the squares of the adjacency matrices of the few possible graphs with $3$ vertices, the answer is yes.

In my question, I assume that it is known that $S=A^2$ is the square of the adjacency matrix of a graph and I wonder if there is another graph whose adjacency matrix has also $S$ for square. So a reformulation of the question is

**Does it exist two adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ (as defined in the first paragraph) such that $A^2=B^2$?**

Comment: Your last bolded question may need disambiguation - "two adjacency matrices *for non-equivalent graphs*".

Comment: If there is actually non-uniqueness of squares of graphs, my hunch is that counterexamples can be found among bipartite graphs.

Comment: Section 3 in this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3122.pdf) seems to address your question. This [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101428) might also be relevant.

Comment: I deleted my answer, it was stupid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking $n=4$: any graph consisting of two disjoint edges gives $A^2=I$. There are $3$ such graphs on a given vertex set of size $4$ (but of course they are all isomorphic).

For an example of two non-isomorphic graphs giving the same square: let $n=6$, and consider either a $6$-cycle graph, or a graph consisting of two disjoint $3$-cycles.

Comment: I don't understand your example for n = 6: a disjoint union of two 3-cycles has adjacency matrix which is a direct sum (of two 3x3 matrices), while a 6-cycle does not, and the squares of their adjacency matrices don't even have the same zero pattern

Comment: @math54321If the 6-cycle looks like $1-2-3-4-5-6-1$, then organise the rows and columns so that the first 3 rows / columns correspond to vertices 1,3,5 and the last 3 correspond to 2,4,6.  In particular, letting $X$ and $Y$ be the two squared adjacency matrices, there's a permutation matrix $P$ (that performs the swap mentioned in sentence 1 of this comment) such that $X$ and $Y$ are similar via $P$: so $X = PYP^{-1}$.

Comment: @math54321 The two graphs could be $\{1-2-3-4-5-6-1\}$ and $\{1-3-5-1 \,, \,2-4-6-2\}$. Isn't it the case that for any $i$ and $j$, the number of length-$2$ walks from $i$ to $j$ is the same in both graphs?

Comment: Ah I see @BrandonduPreez and responded almost simultaneously :)

Comment: Thanks @BrandonduPreez and James for the clarification. I think it's important to specify the exact graph (labeled with edges/vertices) when talking about the adjacency matrix, not just the isomorphism type of the graph (which only gives the adjacency matrix up to conjugation by permutation matrices)

Comment: @math54321 The permutation matrix conjugation I described gives you the adjacency matrix *of the same graph* (not just isomorphism type) just with a different "ordering" on the vertices.

Answer (score 13):

The answer is no - you cannot recover the graph.

You state that what is known is the number of common neighbours between any two vertices. There is a nice class of graphs, [Strongly regular graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph#), which are essentially defined according to how many common neighbours any pair of vertices have. In particular, a graph is an $(n,k,\lambda, \mu)$ strongly regular graph if it has $n$ vertices, is $k$-regular, every pair of adjacent vertices has $\lambda$ common neighbours, and every pair of nonadjacent vertices has $\mu$ common neighbours.

Per the wikipedia article linked (or just by direct calculation with the above parameters), the adjacency matrix $A$ of an $(n,k,\lambda, \mu)$ strongly regular graph satisfies:

$$A^2 = kI + \lambda A + \mu(J-I-A)$$

Where $J$ is an all $1$s matrix, and I is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Thus, any two strongly regular graphs with the same parameters, in which $\lambda = \mu$, have the same squared adjacency matrix! To see this, suppose $\lambda = \mu$, and re-arrange the above equation to get:

$$A^2 = kI + \lambda A + \lambda(J-I-A)$$
$$A^2 = kI + \lambda A + \lambda(J-I) - \lambda A$$
$$A^2 = kI + \lambda(J-I)$$

And indeed there are two strongly regular graphs, with the same parameters, that have $\mu = \lambda$. They are the [(4,4) Rook Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RookGraph.html) and the [Shrikhande Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShrikhandeGraph.html), both of which are $(16,6,2,2)$ strongly regular graphs.